# handling arrays with missmatched sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I want to make a function in python that allows broadcasting between two mismatched arrays. I am new to python and I have tried many things like reshape or newaxis but I cannot make it work. Could someone explain to me how to do it? For any dimension, the size of one array should be a multiple of the other array like below.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
arr2 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
```

Comment: What exactly would your function do?

Comment: Please show examples of what you're trying to achieve. Right now it isn't clear what you're asking or what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [numpy.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) or [numpy.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) can help you. `tile` repeats the array as a whole and `repeat` works element wise:

```py
a3 = np.arange(3)               # array([0, 1, 2])
a6t = np.tile(a, reps=2)        # array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
a6r = np.repeat(a, repeats=2)   # array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

With both operations you can *repeat* your array along one or multiple axis to match the other:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
arr2 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

arr2_t = np.tile(arr2, reps=(2, 1))
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5]])
arr2_r = np.repeat(arr2, repeats=2, axis=0)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [3, 4, 5]])

arr3 = arr - arr2_t
arr4 = arr * arr2_r
```

Note the slightly different call signature for both functions.

In general:

- `tile` uses *reps* (`tuple`) to specify the (possible different) repetitions for each axis
- `repeat` uses  *repeats* to specify how often each element along the *axis* (`int`) should be repeated, *repeats* will be broadcasted to fit the axis

  - `np.repeat(a=range(3), repeats=3)  # array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])`
  - `np.repeat(a=range(4), repeats=range(4) # array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeating arrays.

For a specific example here, you could add the two arrays as follows:

```
out = arr + np.tile(arr2, (2, 1))
#Output:
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [12, 14, 16]])
```

For a more general purpose function, it gets slightly more involved, but the approach is simple: figure out the correct shape of the output array by checking the max values along each axis. Then individually use tile to achieve the desired shape.

```
def broadcast_arr(arr1, arr2):
    ''' takes two arrays. 
    returns two arrays broadcasted to the maximum shape
    corresponding to the input array for elementwise operations if possible
    '''
    shape1 = arr1.shape
    shape2 = arr2.shape
    shape_out = max(len(shape1), len(shape2))
    temp = np.ones((2, shape_out), dtype='int')
    temp[0][-len(shape1):] = shape1
    temp[1][-len(shape2):] = shape2
    shape_out = temp.max(0)
    if (shape_out % temp).any():
        raise ValueError("incompatible arrays provided")
    out1 = np.tile(arr1, shape_out // temp[0])
    out2 = np.tile(arr2, shape_out // temp[1])
    return out1, out2

temp1, temp2 = broadcast_arr(arr, arr2)
out = temp1 + temp2
#Output:
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [12, 14, 16]])
out.shape #(4, 3)
```